# Simple Subquery takes too long, are there any options?

Tags: mysql

I can't work out how to get this subquery very slow to get data in 10k record

table_code:

```
+--------+-----------+------------+
| code_id| code_name | code_date  |
+--------+-----------+------------+
|    1   |     A1    | 2017-02-01 |
|    2   |     A2    | 2017-02-02 |
|    3   |     A3    | 2017-02-03 |
|    4   |     A4    | 2017-02-04 |
|    5   |     A5    | 2017-02-05 |
|    6   |     A6    | 2017-02-06 |
|    7   |     A7    | 2017-02-07 |
|10000   | A10000    | 2017-02-22 |
+--------+-----------+------------+
```

table_reg:

```
+--------+------------+------------+
| reg_id | reg_number | reg_date   |
+--------+------------+------------+
|    1   |   1010     | 2017-02-01 |
|    2   |   1020     | 2017-02-02 |
|    3   |   1030     | 2017-02-03 |
|    4   |   1040     | 2017-02-04 |
|    5   |   1050     | 2017-02-05 |
|    6   |   1060     | 2017-02-06 |
|    7   |   1070     | 2017-02-07 |
|10000   | 101010     | 2017-02-22 |
+--------+-----------+------------+
```

Then i run:

```
SELECT
a.`code_name`,
a.`code_date`,
(SELECT b.`reg_number` FROM `table_reg` b WHERE b.`reg_date` <= a.`code_date` ORDER BY b.`reg_date` DESC LIMIT 1) AS `reg_number`,
(SELECT b.`reg_date` FROM `table_reg` b WHERE b.`reg_date` <= a.`code_date` ORDER BY b.`reg_date` DESC LIMIT 1) AS `reg_date`
FROM `table_code` a
```

Result:

```
+-----------+------------+------------+------------+
| code_name | code_date  | reg_number | reg_date   |
+-----------+------------+------------+------------+
|     A1    | 2017-02-01 | 1010       | 2017-02-01 |
|     A2    | 2017-02-02 | 1020       | 2017-02-02 |
|     A3    | 2017-02-03 | 1030       | 2017-02-03 |
|     A4    | 2017-02-04 | 1040       | 2017-02-04 |
|     A5    | 2017-02-05 | 1050       | 2017-02-05 |
|     A6    | 2017-02-06 | 1050       | 2017-02-05 |
|     A7    | 2017-02-07 | 1050       | 2017-02-05 |
| A10000    | 2017-02-22 | 1050       | 2017-02-05 |
+-----------+------------+------------|------------+
```

DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE `table_reg` (
  `reg_id` INTEGER(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `reg_number` INTEGER(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reg_date` DATE DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`reg_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `table_reg_idx1` (`reg_date`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=4 CHARACTER SET 'latin1' COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci'
COMMENT='InnoDB free: 7168 kB; InnoDB free: 6144 kB';

CREATE TABLE `table_code` (
  `code_id` INTEGER(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `code_name` VARCHAR(20) COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `code_date` DATE DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`code_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `table_code_idx1` (`code_date`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=8 CHARACTER SET 'latin1' COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci'
COMMENT='InnoDB free: 7168 kB; InnoDB free: 6144 kB';
```

Result works as expected but it is very slow with 10k record,

If code_date can't match with reg_date_date, it will using reg_number the latest date.

```
(SELECT b.`reg_number` FROM `table_reg` b WHERE b.`reg_date` <= a.`code_date` ORDER BY b.`reg_date` DESC LIMIT 1) AS `reg_number`
```

Are there any other options query?

This link sqlfiddle:  [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f090ad/1]

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

EXPLAIN result sample table:
[image]

Comment: Your tables have no indexes.

Comment: They have PK's- should be indexed AFAIK

Comment: `WHERE b.reg_date <= a.code_date` - you need at least an index on `b.reg_date`.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel: Sorry, you're right- the whole thing works with dates only.

Comment: Sorry not mention before, PK, code_date and reg_date already Indexes too

Comment: And still very slow. Takes >30sec 10k record

Comment: @KomporMleduk I don't see any indexes in your DDL.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel, edited. Sorry this is sample table

Comment: Post [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html) result.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel, EXPLAIN result like that. Thank you

Comment: This part `WHERE b.reg_date <= a.code_date ORDER BY b.reg_date DESC` seams to be a problem for MySQL. Changing the condition to `>=` or the order to `ASC` would give you a result almost instantly. But it would be a wrong result.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, your current approach might run with acceptable speed if you add appropriate indices.  But one alternative to your current query would be to use a row number approach.

```
SET @row_number = 1;

SELECT t.code_name,
       t.code_date,
       t.reg_number,
       t.reg_date
FROM
(
    SELECT @row_number:=CASE WHEN @code_id = t1.code_id
                             THEN @row_number + 1 ELSE 1 END AS rn,
           @code_id:=t1.code_id AS code_id,
           t1.code_name,
           t1.code_date,
           t2.reg_number,
           t2.reg_date
    FROM table_code t1
    INNER JOIN table_reg t2
        ON t2.reg_date <= t1.code_date
    ORDER BY t1.code_id, t2.reg_date DESC
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

Comment: `INNER JOIN table_reg t2  ON t2.reg_date <= t1.code_date` - Looks like a cross join to me. If the real data looks like the sample data your subquery will result in a 50M-rows temp table.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel `Looks like a cross join to me` , no it's not a cross join because there is an `ON` clause.  In any case, using space may not be the problem so much as running time.  The OP requires doing _two_ subqueries for each _row_ of the `table_code` table.  At least my approach would require only a single join and one subquery.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen. Why all record reg_number and reg_date similar?

Comment: I don't understand your comment.